# Previewing before publishing to Azure causes files to be deleted from the deployment location

Tags: asp.net, azure, msbuild, msdeploy, msbuild-target

I have a nuget package that contains an build target file that add files when the project is published to Azure.

I've gotten this to work, but if I press the "Start Preview" button in the publish dialog before I press publish, the nuget-package-files are not published and if they exist on the server they are deleted.

This is the content of the build target file

```
<ItemGroup>
    <LisaFrontendFiles Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\Web\**\*" />
    <NativeBinaries Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\lib\native\*" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="LisaFrontendPublishTarget" BeforeTargets="CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage">   
    <ItemGroup>
        <FilesForPackagingFromProject  Include="%(LisaFrontendFiles.Identity)">
            <DestinationRelativePath>%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
        </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(NativeBinaries.Identity)">
            <DestinationRelativePath>bin/%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
        </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>

<PropertyGroup>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
        LisaFrontendPublishTarget;
        $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```